# Generate source code with for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, code-generation

I have two classes C1 and C2 that can generate C++ code via method `printCode()`. Using objects of C1, C2, I can generate C++ code as follow:

```
C1* array1[100];
C2* array2[100];

// Create objects to generate code
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    array1[i] = new C1(i);
    array2[i] = new C2(i);
}
[...]
// Generate code
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    array1[i]->printCode();
    array2[i]->printCode();
}
```

The generated code:

```
// f represents a set of operations
// code generated by array1[0], array2[0]
(x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]) := f(0, x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]); 
// code generated by array1[1], array2[1]
(x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]) := f(1, x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]);
[...]
// code generated by array1[99], array2[99]
(x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]) := f(99, x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]);
```

How can I generate this instead (same output, smaller code size):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    (x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]) := f(i, x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]);
```

Edit: Example definitions of C1, C2:

```
const int n = 1000; 
class C1 {
public:
    C1(int x) : my_var(x) {}
    void printCode() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            // func1 is defined in the generated code
            // the generated code sees foo(my_var) as a constant
            cout << "x[" << i << "] = func1(x[" << i << "], x[" << i + 1 "] + " << bar(my_var) << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int my_var;
    int foo(int x) { ... }
}
```

C2 is similar:

```
class C2 {
public:
    C2(int x) : my_var(x) {}
    void printCode() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            // func2 is defined in the generated code
            // the generated code sees bar(my_var) as a constant
            cout << "x[" << i << "] = func2(x[" << i << "], x[" << i + 1 "] + " << bar(my_var) << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int my_var;
    int bar(int x) { ... }
}
```

With C1, C2 defined as above, the generated code would be:

```
// definitions of func1, func2
int func1(int x, int y) { ... }
int func2(int x, int y) { ... }

...

// Code generated by C1(0)
x[0] = func1(x[0], x[1]) + f0;  // f0 = C1.foo(0)
x[1] = func1(x[1], x[2]) + f0;
...
x[998] = func1(x[998], x[999]) + f0;
// Code generated by C2(0)
x[1] = func2(x[0], x[1]) + b0;  // b0 = C2.bar(0)
x[2] = func2(x[1], x[2]) + b0;
...
x[999] = func2(x[998], x[999]) + b0;

// Code generated by C1(1), C2(1)
// Code generated by C1(2), C2(2)
...
// Code generated by C1(99), C2(99)
```

What I want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    x[0] = func1(x[0], x[1]) + f[i];  // f[i] = C1.foo(i)
    x[1] = func1(x[1], x[2]) + f[i];
    ...
    x[998] = func1(x[998], x[999]) + f[i];

    x[1] = func2(x[0], x[1]) + b[i];  // b[i] = C2.bar(i)
    x[2] = func2(x[1], x[2]) + b[i];
    ...
    x[999] = func2(x[998], x[999]) + b[i];
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details on how your classes `C1` and `C2` implemented

Comment: @teivaz I have added the code for C1, C2.

Comment: Apparently the examples I added cause some confusion. The for loop inside `printCode()` is just to illustrate that the function prints a lot of code. In my application, printCode() cannot be optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is some form of abstract representation of the for loop. So instead of writing a loop from 1 to 100, you create on object of type loop like this:

```
auto loop = createLoop("int", "i", 1, 100);
loop->add( createC1("i") );
loop->add( createC2("i") );
loop->printCode(stdout);
```

by encapsulating the constructors in factory methods, you can let the factory methods return `unique_ptr`, and therefore avoid memory leaks, and getting rid of all the manual tracking of heap objects (don't use raw new at all in your codebase).

C1 and C2 need a way, that they can store symbols instead of just constants, like you have. Best way to support that, to let them have a string value as member instead of an int.

printCode from loop has to call printCode from it's members C1 and C2.

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably be something like:

```
void printCode() {
    cout << "for (int i = 0; i < " << n - 1 << " ; i++) {" << endl;
        // func2 is defined in the generated code
        // the generated code sees bar(my_var) as a constant
    cout << "x[i] = func2(x[i], x[i + 1] + " << bar(my_var) << ");" << endl;
    cout << "}" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my explanation was unclear. Your fix would create: `code_generated_by C1[0], C2[0]; code_generated_by C1[1], C2[1]; ...; code_generated_by C1[99], C2[99]`. What I wanted was: `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { code_generated_by C1[i], C2[i]; }`

Comment: uhm, in such case you cannot invoke that in loop. What code is generated depends on how you invoke the methods (i.e., if you invoke `C1, C2, C1, C2`, that's exactly what's going to be generated). You need a wrapper generator.

Comment: So basically a generator that generates a generator?

Comment: kindof, yes. If you want a single loop, you need a single call to `generateCode` - perhaps it'd be sufficient to have a generator parametrized with loop count _and_ C1/C2 arguments that internally knows how to generate C1/C2. Or, if you aim for more reuse, a templated "loop" generator that would require C1/C2 only to implement the stuff that is printed in the loop and that handles the loop itself